# SQL - Select by level or is parent when null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm doing a query where I have the following data:

[image]

What I want is to get data by level.
That is, if the "User" column is not NULL, I want your Business + Type + Class combination returned.

In turn, if the "User" column is NULL, I want the Business + Type + Class combination to be obtained from the Agency column.

Finally, if the "User" column and the "Agency" column are NULL, I want to return the combination from the "Country" column.

Expected output is green lines:

[image]

Can someone help me? 
Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work? Please don't supply sample data as an image, you know we can't consume it. It should be formatted as tabular formatted `text` or as DDL and DML statements please. What do you mean the expected outputs is the green lines? Then infers a `WHERE` but you describe some kind on concatenation. Show us what the result you're actually after are.

Comment: I'm trying change it! Sorry

Comment: "I'm doing a query ..."  Where's the query???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a prioritization query.  All rows where the user is not null, plus additionally one row per `null`.  One method is `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by business, type, agency order by userid desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 or user is not null;
```

The `desc` puts the nulls last in the sequence, so they are filtered out by the `where`.

Another approach uses `union all` and `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.user is not null
union all
select t.*
from t
where t.user is null and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.business = t.business and
                        t2.type = t.type and
                        t2.class = t.class and
                        t2.user is not null
                 );
```

The first version is handy if your results are the result of a query, because the query results are only referenced (and hence calculated) once.

Comment: Great! Thanks! I added IS NULL to each where clauses to return null values too (t.business IS NULL OR t.business = t2.business). Finally, I have a temp table and insert values by level (user not null, then user null and agency not null and finally, user and agency null). Thanks!